# Run time error 3075 syntax error on update query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

i am having an issue with writing an update query in SQL where there are two clauses one of which has two scenerarios identified with an AND function.

The run time error i am getting is 3075 stating there is syntax errors on the where expression.  Loooking at it and after doing a lot of research, i imagine i am almost there.

Thanks, A

```
st_sql = "UPDATE tblSearchEngine01 SET tblSearchEngine01.Query01OpenItems =""" & _
    "WHERE (((tblSearchEngine01.Status)='open')) OR (((tblSearchEngine01.Overall_status)    <>'complete') AND ((tblSearchEngine01.Status) Is Null))"
```

Comment: why all these parentheses?

Comment: i am using MS Access SQL generator. It has suggested them.. Shall i get rid of them?

Comment: Well, I certainly would

Comment: I am getting the same error message :(

Comment: Is it possible that the quotation marks are causing a problem?

Comment: st_sql = "UPDATE tblSearchEngine01 SET tblSearchEngine01.Query01OpenItems =""" & _
        "WHERE tblSearchEngine01.Status='open' OR tblSearchEngine01.Overall_status<>'complete' AND tblSearchEngine01.Status Is Null"
        Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you mean :(

Comment: Lorenzo Meyer figured it out. It was in the update line..  (I believe you were getting there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error is not where you suspect. Two quotes inside a quoted string are interpreted as one quote. You need to double your quotes here :

```
 st_sql = "UPDATE tblSearchEngine01 SET tblSearchEngine01.Query01OpenItems =""""" & _
```

Consider using single quotes for SQL statements, as this will improve readability.

```
 st_sql = "UPDATE tblSearchEngine01 SET tblSearchEngine01.Query01OpenItems = ''" & _
```